# A graph $G=(V,E)$ is connected and its edge $e$ lies on a cycle. Prove that the graph $G^{'} = (V,E-\{e\})$ is connected.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity

A graph $G=(V,E)$ is connected and its edge $e$ lies on a cycle. Prove that, then the graph $G^{'} = (V,E)$ is connected, that is deleting edge of the cycle doesn't violate the connectivity.

How to prove this theorem. I need hint/resource recommendation.

Comment: If a cycle containing $e$ is $ee_1e_2...e_n$ and $v_1,v_2\in V$ were connected by a path containing $e$, then you can replace $e$ in that path by $e_ne_{n-1}...e_2e_1$. Essentially, instead of using $e$, you got around the remaining part of the cycle.

Comment: "**its** edge $e$ lies on a cycle" is bad English. That phrase insinuates that graph $G$ has only one edge. For example, if had a sphere then we might discuss "its radius." That is because a sphere has exactly one radius. Likewise, in computer programming, a class can have at most one member variable of a given name. For example, you could write a class named "`Shoe`." Every `Shoe` has a size. If $x$ is a Shoe, then we could talk about "**its** size."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Definition of Connectivity

The following is similar to the definition of connectivity found in many textbooks:

> A graph $G$ is *connected*
>  if and only if
> for any vertices $v$ and $w$,
>  there exists at least one path in graph $G$ starting at $v$ and ending at $w$

#### Some Remarks on the Definition of Connectivity

Path and walks begin at a dot (a vertex). You then travel to a neighboring dot. You repeat this process until arriving at some destination dot.

- *paths* are usually defined so that a path never revisits a node.
- A *walk* is like a path, except that a *walk* is allowed to visit a node it has visited before.

The definition of connectivity is *bad* if the definition talks about *paths*.

This is because a graph is connected if and only if there exists a ***walk*** between every pair of nodes.

Suppose that a graph can be divided into two separate pieces $L$ and $R$ so that no edge (line segment) crosses the gap between $L$ and $R$

[image: AN EXAMPLE OF A DISCONNECTED GRAPH]

If you cannot get to vertex $w$ from vertex $v$, then it does not matter if you repeat nodes on your journey or not. That is, it does not matter if we talk about paths, or walks, when it comes to connectivity.

#### The Relationship between a Cycle and Two paths

A cycle is can be viewed as two paths which have been glued end-to-end.

[image: TWO PATHS BECOME ONE CYCLE]

A cycle is the same as two paths which have been glued end-to-end.

If you delete one of the paths in a cycle, then there is still one path remaining.

#### Sketch of a Proof

Let $G$ be a graph $G$ such that graph $G$ contains a cycle.

Suppose that $v$ and $w$ are nodes on the cycle and that $e = \{v, w\}$ is an edge in the cycle.

We now destroy an edge $\{v, w\}$ in the cycle to form graph $G-\{v, w\}$

Consider any walk in graph $G$ from a node $a$ to a node $b$

Suppose that the walk from $a$ to $b$ contained edge $\{v, w\}$.

After edge $e$ is deleted, how do we get from node $a$ to node $b$?

Edge $\{v, w\}$ can be viewed as a very short path.

A cycle is the union of two non-overlapping paths.

Thus, we replace edge $\{v, w\}$ with the path from the cycle which does not contain ede $\{v, w\}$.

This gives us a new walk with the same starting and ending vertices.

If the old walk was a path (did not repeat vertices), then the new walk might repeat vertices.

It is okay if the new walk repeats vertices. A graph is connected if and only if there exists a walk between every pair of vertices. It is okay for there to exist at least one vertex in the graph which is visited more than once on the walk.

#### Definition of Walk

Suppose that $m$ is a whole number, such as 1, 2, 3, 964, etc...
A walk in graph $G$ is a mapping $F$ from $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \leq n \leq m\}$ to dots (vertices) in graph $G$ such that if $k$ is a whole number between $1$ and $m$ then there is an edge/line between dot $F(k)$ and dot $F(k+1)$ in graph $G$.

A walk must contain at least one node.

It is possible, but unusual, for a walk contain only one node. Usually, there are many nodes in the walk under discussion.